# Portability of exporting a c++ class via virtual interface class

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, language-lawyer

I want to write a library that should be usable as a plug-in. The library is written in C++ and should also be used in C++ code. I found [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28969/HowTo-Export-C-classes-from-a-DLL#Introduction) which describes how to export a c++ class via a purely virtual interface structure, which is visible to the user. In short, the code looks as follows:

```
struct VirtualInterface
{
    virtual MyExportedFunction() = 0;
}

class MyInterfaceImplementer : public VirtualInterface
{
    ...
    virtual MyExportedFunction(){...}
    ...
}

extern "C" MyAPI VirtualInterface* Factory(); // The only exported function
```

The author of the article states at some point that:

> A hypothetical C++ compiler that fails to support COM efficiently is
>   doomed to oblivion in the Windows market. That is why ,nowadays,
>   exposing a C++ class from a DLL via an abstract interface will work
>   reliably with every decent C++ compiler on the Windows platform.

Do I get it right that this way of exporting a C++ class relies on the compiler implementation and is not guaranteed to work by the standard? If yes, is there a portable way except via creating a C interface which exports every single function of the interface?

Comment: Yes, C++ does not have a standard ABI, so for robust applications, it is often advisable to create a pure C wrapper. That wrapper can also stop all exceptions at the boundary and convert them to old-skool C return codes - primitive but robust.

Comment: @ErikAlapää My plug-ins needs to run on UNIX systems. So it sounds as if I have to live with the C export. Thanks.

Comment: @PaulR. This point means that you can use your pure interface-based library with any COM-friendly compiler. You also can export a class without interfaces. In this case you must warrant that both library and user module are built with the same compiler and linker, with similar options (e.g. both debug or release).

Comment: The standard doesn't mention DLLs or shared libraries or loadable plugins. In practice what you have described just works on all common platforms. If you only target users of C++, *and* willing to assume they will be using the same C++ compiler as you, there is no need to resort to C or COM or other such nonsense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can portably export a C++ class/interface [on GNU/Linux and BSD because compilers support Itanium ABI](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compatibility.html):

> Starting with GCC 3.2, GCC binary conventions for C++ are based on a written, vendor-neutral C++ ABI that was designed to be specific to 64-bit Itanium but also includes generic specifications that apply to any platform. This C++ ABI is also implemented by other compiler vendors on some platforms, notably GNU/Linux and BSD systems. We have tried hard to provide a stable ABI that will be compatible with future GCC releases, but it is possible that we will encounter problems that make this difficult. Such problems could include different interpretations of the C++ ABI by different vendors, bugs in the ABI, or bugs in the implementation of the ABI in different compilers. GCC’s -Wabi switch warns when G++ generates code that is probably not compatible with the C++ ABI.

However, if classes from the C++ standard library are exposed in the interface, the implementation and the consumer of the API must use the same C++ library implementation:

> The C++ library used with a C++ compiler includes the Standard C++ Library, with functionality defined in the C++ Standard, plus language runtime support. The runtime support is included in a C++ ABI, but there is no formal ABI for the Standard C++ Library. Two implementations of that library are interoperable if one follows the de-facto ABI of the other and if they are both built with the same compiler, or with compilers that conform to the same ABI for C++ compiler and runtime support.
>
> When G++ and another C++ compiler conform to the same C++ ABI, but the implementations of the Standard C++ Library that they normally use do not follow the same ABI for the Standard C++ Library, object files built with those compilers can be used in the same program only if they use the same C++ library. This requires specifying the location of the C++ library header files when invoking the compiler whose usual library is not being used.

This also likely holds true for Windows compilers because of the aforementioned requirement to support COM. There was a wrinkle with destructors though: COM does not use destructors, so two compilers supporting COM may differ in where they put the destructor pointer in the v-table.

Answer (score 0):

In Doom 3 game, engine executable **Doom3.exe** dynamically loads gameplay from **gamex86.dll**. The game engine interfaces are exposed via virtual functions exactly as you describe (see [review](https://fabiensanglard.net/doom3/index.php)). This works perfectly well on Windows and Linux, allowing to create mods (e.g. [TheDarkMod](https://wiki.thedarkmod.com/index.php?title=DarkMod_and_Doom3_linkage) used to live like that).

The usual issues related to dynamic linking apply of course:

1. CRT library: linking it statically means you have to be careful about what you pass across DLL boundary. Linking it dynamically means everyone have to use same major version of compiler, at least in case of Visual Studio.
2. Using STL in interface is a terribly bad idea, because then everyone will have to use the same major version of Visual Studio and the same type of CRT (debug/release) on Windows.